# Oracle Data Integrator and odiRef.getSession

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm having some troubles with ODI logs. 
I'm trying to get the logs from the Snp_session, using the session number from  this:

```
select <%=odiRef.getSession("SESS_NO")%> from dual
```

Unfortunately, it's not always right, and actualy it get the wrong session number quite often, like 1 every 10 times.
Is it an expected behaviour, or is there another way to get the right session?

Edit:
Corrected mistyping error

Comment: No it's not the expected behaviour, it's supposed to give you the right session number all the time. Where do you use that select statement? In a variable, a procedure or a KM step? To what do you compare to tell it's not the right session number? Also wich version of ODI are you using?

Comment: I use it in a variable and refresh it in a package. I confront it to the snp_session session_no, and it seems it get the session number wrong by just one, since I've been found the right log just by adding 1 to the session number.
As for the version, we are currently using the Data Integrator Version 12.2.1
Build ODI_12.2.1.2.0_GENERIC_161008.2132

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this is working at all… Last time I checked (ODI 11g) this syntax required extra `=` character (passing over output from ODI Substitution API directly). Can you try:

```
SELECT <%=odiRef.getSession("SESS_NO")%> FROM dual
```

?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I just mistyped, there is actualy that =